# How to sort within partitions (and avoid sort across the partitions) using RDD API?

Tags: apache-spark

It is Hadoop MapReduce shuffle's default behavior to sort the shuffle key within partition, but not cross partitions(It is the total ordering that makes keys sorted cross the parttions)

I would ask how to achieve the same thing using Spark RDD(sort within Partition,but not sort cross the partitions)

1. RDD's `sortByKey` method is doing total ordering
2. RDD's `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` is doing sort within partition but not cross partitions, but unfortunately it adds an extra step to do repartition.

Is there a direct way to sort within partition but not cross partitions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `Dataset` and `sortWithinPartitions` method:

```scala
import spark.implicits._

sc.parallelize(Seq("e", "d", "f", "b", "c", "a"), 2)
  .toDF("text")
  .sortWithinPartitions($"text")
  .show

+----+
|text|
+----+
|   d|
|   e|
|   f|
|   a|
|   b|
|   c|
+----+
```

In general shuffle is an important factor in sorting partitions because it reuse shuffle structures to sort without loading all data into memory at once.

Comment: Thanks @user7849215  for the helpful answer. Is there way to do sortWithinPartitions with raw RDD?

Answer (score 0):

I've never had this need before, but my first guess would be to use any of the `*Partition*` methods (e.g. `foreachPartition` or `mapPartitions`) to do the sorting within every partition.

Since they give you a Scala `Iterator`, you could use `it.toSeq` and then apply any of the sorting methods of [Seq](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html), e.g. `sortBy` or `sortWith` or `sorted`.

Comment: If the data in the partition is very large, then scala sort may cause OOM?

Comment: Correct! Are you looking for dump-to-disk-on-demand version of sort in Spark?

Comment: Thanks @jacek-laskowski, i am really wondering why RDD#repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions is implemented as repartition first and then sort. As far as I know, repartition or shuffle doesn't involve sort at all. Sort based shuffle only revolves sort by partitionId.

Comment: My guess is that it is to make sure that all elements for given expression(s) are in the same partitions? Exploring SortExec physical operator in Spark SQL as we speak so I might have more details in the coming days.

Comment: Thanks @jacek-laskowski. I looked at SortExec，when doing within partition sort（not global sort), it doesn't have requirement on its child's data distribution, it just asks UnspecifiedDistribution

Comment: Correct. Does this make sense? How does that change our conversation? I'm asking since I'm still in an exploration mode.

Comment: How can we do sortWithinPartition in JavaPairRDD?

Comment: @Devavrata Can you ask a separate question? Leave the link here.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski Here is the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77929621/how-can-we-sort-within-partition-without-shuffling-data-in-javapairrdd