# How to sort the content of a partition in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

The `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` method works great.

But I don't really want to re-partition.  I am happy with the way data is partitioned naturally.

I do want to sort the content of each partition.

I am not interested in a total sort.

Essentially, I want to avoid the reshuffling of data.  I just need to get each partition content sorted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort within partitions (and avoid sort across the partitions) using RDD API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43339027/how-to-sort-within-partitions-and-avoid-sort-across-the-partitions-using-rdd-a)

Comment: You can improve the title.

Comment: @ollik1 - thank you I did go through that question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this sorts the data within the partition.

```
df.sortWithinPartitions('<sort_column>').show()
```

Comment: Thank you unfortunately I was not able to take advantage of this approach.  I ended up loading the content of each partition into an ArrayList and sorting the ArrayList.  Given my partition size and the container size, I don't think I'll run into an OOM.  I will mark this as the correct answer.