# How can we sort within Partition without shuffling data in JavaPairRDD?

Tags: apache-spark, java-pair-rdd

Strangley JavaPairRDD doesn't have sortWithinPartition but instead it expects [repartitionAndSortWithinPartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions-org.apache.spark.Partitioner-). To implement this I had to write an Identical partitioner which returns the same partition for records in same partition.

Do we have any other better way to solve this?

Comment: any one from the overloaded `sortByKey()` bunch won't do??